# How to increase value on label score after each obstacle passed on passing obstacle game on windows form c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am making a simple game similar to crossy road game and my game game looks like this :
[image]

Im using timer to make the obstacle moving down and if my green character(button) didn't hit the obstacle (blue and red colored lable), it will increase the score for each obstacle passed.
The problem is i dont know how to increase the score for each obstacle passed.

I tried to make code to increase the score. Here is my code :

```
int score = 0;
private void timerMovement_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control wall in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (wall is Label)
            {
                if (wall.Text == "")
                {
                    wall.Top += 20;
                    if (wall .Top > button2.Top)
                    {
                        score += Convert.ToInt32(wall.Tag);
                        labelScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

But when i start the game, the score keep increasing overtime after i pass the first obstacle which i dont want this to happen. I want the score only increasing only after i pass one obstacle.

Anyone can help me make the check statement ? thank you

Comment: I can't see the entire code, but if, for example, a player evade a wall, the same number of wall moves. Then you can add a second variable int / long moveScore and count your moves. And if you know that, for example, every 20 moves it passes through a wall, save it with score = moveScore / 20;

Comment: Can i put the check statement on timer event ? Or where should i put it ?

Comment: wall.Tag defines the score to add? if so, you could set `wall.Tag = 0` when you apply the score

Comment: @Verlanderstore I add only sample. Because you haven't shown how you move objects. I assume that for the same number of movements of one of the objects, the player bypasses the wall. And I would just add this counter over this method where you move it.